# NIM with multiple winning final positions

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I've been looking at a variant of NIM.

> *You can skip this bit where I'll describe NIM as usually described:*
>
> There's a starting position with some number of piles of counters and
> two players alternate taking any number of counters from any single pile.
> In "normal play" the player who takes all of the last
> non-empty pile wins.
> In "misère play" the player forced to take the last pile loses.
> That pile will always be of size one, since otherwise a perfect player
> would take all but one counter from the last pile and force
> the other player to take the lone pile of one.

A "P-position" in a game is one where the previous player has a forced win,
and the person playing next from that position will lose
against a player executing the strategy without error.

The variation I'm exploring is to broaden the winning conditions into
"the first player to reach any one of a set of positions."
In other words, there's a specified set of "seed" P-positions.

The classical normal game seed set for three piles can be recast as {[0,0,0]};
the winning player
is the one to reach the state where all the piles are empty.
The classical misère game seed set is {[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]}.
Plays that make no win possible are not legal: So for example, if
{[1,4,2],[3,5,3]} were the two target winning positions,
a move from [17,21,5] to [17,3,5] would be illegal.

Both classical normal and classical misère NIM have perfect strategies that are
fairly compact to describe, but looking at other sets of seed P-positions,
that seems to be a rarity.

Given a game with some set of seed P-positions,
what is that set of all P-positions for that game?

Has this already been studied?

Even the set of P-positions for {[0,0,0],[1,0,0]} looks chaotic. The solid edges are [0,n,n], [n+1,0, n], and [n, n+1, 0]. Those are all P-positions.

[image: NIM P-positions for up to 64 counters and targets {[0,0,0],[1,0,0]}.]

For {[0,0,0],[1,0,0]} the set of P-positions looks like a hollow tetrahedron, with the sides slightly caved in. Cross-sections of the P-positions with the same number of counters thus look like slightly caved-in sparse triangles. The dense and sparse regions are somewhat coherent as the number of counters changes, but the seeds remain fixed. This makes the whole set of P-positions look like a collection of fans, rooted at [0,0,0].

This is a cross-section of the tetrahedron, showing all the P-positions with 250 counters and targets {[0,0,0],[1,0,0]}.

[image: NIM P-positions for exactly 250 counters in three or fewer piles and targets {[0,0,0],[1,0,0]}.]